# Is there any SDK for yahoo oAuth for Blackberry playbook?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, actionscript-2, blackberry-playbook

I need to integrate yahoo oAuth for my playbook app written using action script(flash). Is there any sample or SDK available which i can refer.

Answer (score 0):

For **yahoo oAuth** the **sdk for flash with guide** is available at

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/yos/

The **documentation** for **oAuth** can be found at

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/yos/classreference/com/yahoo/oauth/OAuthRequest.html